# Calculate time difference to NOW in JPA criteria API

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api

I would like to select the time-difference between a timestamp in a database column and the current time. To avoid clock-drifts in a distributed environment, it seems sensible to use `NOW` as a reference point (instead of the local time by instances).

I am using the JPA criteria-API for selects.

Now, the easy way is to select both the timestamp from the database-row and currentTime and calculate the difference afterwards in Java. This would look something like this:

```
query.select(
  cb.construct(
    SomeObject.class,
    root.get(Entity_.timestamp),
    cb.currentTimestamp()
  )
)
```

This will certainly work as expected, however, it would be more elegant to let the database do the difference.

I have already learned (from another SO question), that there is no DIFF on timestamps. So, is there a JPA-only way to turn an `Expression<Timestamp>` into an `Expression<Long>`? Or are the other questions I found outdated and there is acutally a way to calculate a `diff` for two `Expression<Timestamp>`?

Comment: Have you tried just standard subtraction (in a JPQL query)? Many database time/date implementations are just longs under the covers anyway, so a solution will likely depend on what your database supports - what database are you using, and what options does it have?

Comment: I tried cb.diff() that wouldn't compile. Iḿ not certain right now, why not (and I would have to look it up tomorrow). However, as we aim for database-independence, I wouldn't want a solution which is possibly database dependent. Especially not, where a working solution exists and it is simply a matter of elegance/style...

Comment: JPA likely didn't extend diff support to date/time expressions for a reason, so you likely won't get a database agnostic solution unless JPQL ("Select new SomeObject(root.timestamp - CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) from yourEntity root") works for you.